# Button commands in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I'm trying to make a text adventure with tkinter and I'm slowly getting something together. I'm trying to display commands as they come from room to room but even though the buttons appear, nothing happens when I press them.

`game.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import world
from player import Player
from ui import *

def main():
    gui = Window(root())
    while True:
        gui.mainloop()
    else:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`ui.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import world, tiles, action
from player import Player


class Window(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master=master)
        self.master = master
        self.player = Player()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.master.title("****")
        self.tabs = Tabs(self.master)
        world.load_tiles()
        self.world = world.tile_exists(self.player.location_x, self.player.location_y)
        self.update_main()

    def update_main(self):
        self.world.scene_init()
        self.world.modify_player(self.player)
        self.tabs.update_tab(self.world, self.player)

    def _label(self, master, text, side=None, anchor=None):
        new_label = tk.Label(master, text=text)
        new_label.pack(side=side, anchor=anchor)

    def _button(self, master, text, command, side=None, anchor=None):
        new_button = tk.Button(master, text=text, command=command)
        new_button.pack(side=side, anchor=anchor)


class Tabs(Window):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.nb = ttk.Notebook(self.master)
        nb_1 = ttk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.frame_1 = tk.Frame(nb_1, bg='red', bd=2, relief=tk.SUNKEN, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.frame_1.pack(expand=1, fill='both', side=tk.LEFT)
        self.nb.add(nb_1, text='Game')
        self.nb.pack(expand=1, fill='both', side=tk.LEFT)

    def update_tab(self, world, player):
        avaliable_actions = world.avaliable_actions()
        self._label(self.frame_1, world.display_text(), side=tk.LEFT, anchor=tk.N)
        for action in avaliable_actions:
            self._button(self.frame_1, text=action, command=player.do_action(action, **action.kwargs), side=tk.BOTTOM, anchor=tk.E)


def root():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("600x350+200+200")
    return root
```

`world.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

_world = {}

def tile_exists(x, y):
        """Returns the tile at the given coordinates or None if there is no tile.

        :param x: the x-coordinate in the worldspace
        :param y: the y-coordinate in the worldspace
        :return: the tile at the given coordinates or None if there is no tile
        """
        return _world.get((x, y))

def load_tiles():
    with open('scenes.txt', 'r') as f:
        rows = f.readlines()
    x_max = len(rows[0].split('\t'))
    for y in range(len(rows)):
        cols = rows[y].split('\t')
        for x in range(x_max):
            tile_name = cols[x].replace('\n', '')
            _world[(x, y)] = None if tile_name == '' else getattr(__import__('tiles'),
                tile_name)(x, y)
    return _world
```

`tiles.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import world, action
from player import Player


class MapTile():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


    def display_text(self):
        pass
        # raise NotImplementedError()

    def modify_player(self, the_player):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def adjacent_moves(self):
        moves = []
        if world.tile_exists(self.x + 1, self.y):
            moves.append(action.MoveEast())
        if world.tile_exists(self.x - 1, self.y):
            moves.append(action.MoveWest())
        if world.tile_exists(self.x, self.y - 1):
            moves.append(action.MoveNorth())
        if world.tile_exists(self.x, self.y + 1):
            moves.append(action.MoveSouth())
        return moves

    def avaliable_actions(self):
        '''Returns all of the default avaliable_actions in a room'''
        moves = self.adjacent_moves()
        # moves.append(action.ViewInventory())
        return moves

class Scene_1(MapTile):
    def scene_init(self):
        self.location = 'Scene_1'
        self.long_desc = 'Welcome to {}, the shittiest place on earth.'.format(self.location)
        self.short_desc = 'Eh, I don\'t care.'

    def display_text(self):
        return self.long_desc

    def modify_player(self, the_player):
        self.first = True
        return self.display_text()

class Scene_2(MapTile):
    def scene_init(self):
        self.location = 'Scene_2'
        self.long_desc = 'This is {}, but noone gives a damn.'.format(self.location)
        self.short_desc = 'Eh, I don\'t care, really.'

    def display_text(self):
        return self.long_desc

    def modify_player(self, the_player):
        self.first = True
        return self.display_text()
```

`player.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Player():
    '''Base for player'''
    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = []
        self.hp = 100
        self.location_x, self.location_y = 1, 1
        self.victory = False

    def is_alive(self):
        return self.hp >= 0

    def do_action(self, action, **kwargs):
        action_method = getattr(self, action.method.__name__)
        if action_method:
            action_method(**kwargs)

    def print_inventory(self):
        for item in self.inventory:
            print(item, 'n')

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.location_x += dx
        self.location_y += dy

    def move_north(self):
        self.move(dx=0, dy=-1)

    def move_south(self):
        self.move(dx=0, dy=1)

    def move_east(self):
        self.move(dx=1, dy=0)

    def move_west(self):
        self.move(dx=-1, dy=0)
```

`action.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from player import Player

class Action():
    def __init__(self, method, name, **kwargs):
        """Creates a new action

        :param method: the function object to execute
        :param name: the name of the action
        :param ends_turn: True if the player is expected to move after this action else False
        :param hotkey: The keyboard key the player should use to initiate this action
        """
        self.method = method
        self.name = name
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)

class MoveNorth(Action):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(method=Player.move_north, name='north')

class MoveSouth(Action):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(method=Player.move_south, name='south')


class MoveEast(Action):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(method=Player.move_east, name='east')


class MoveWest(Action):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(method=Player.move_west, name='west')


class ViewInventory(Action):
    """Prints the player's inventory"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(method=Player.print_inventory, name='View inventory', hotkey='i')


class Attack(Action):
    def __init__(self, enemy):
        super().__init__(method=Player.attack, name="Attack", hotkey='a', enemy=enemy)


class Flee(Action):
    def __init__(self, tile):
        super().__init__(method=Player.flee, name="Flee", hotkey='f', tile=tile)
```

Comment: did you run it in console to see error messages ? maybe you have error message and you don't know it.

Comment: Yeah, nothing prints to console.

Comment: `while True: gui.mainloop()` I'm not saying this is your problem but mainloop itself is already an infinite loop. There is no need for while True.

Comment: mistake: `command=player.do_action(action, **action.kwargs)` this way you assign to `command` value returned by `player.do_action()` but this functions returns `None`

Comment: So I'm gonna have to find a way to link the direct command and that parameter. Makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`command` expect function name without `()` and arguments.

Mistake:

```
command=player.do_action(action, **action.kwargs)
```

This way you assign to `command` value returned by `player.do_action()` but this functions returns `None`

You have to use `lambda` function

```
command=lambda:player.do_action(action, **action.kwargs)
```

but maybe you will need also arguments in `lambda` because you create this in `for` loop.

```
command=lambda act=action, kws=action.kwargs : player.do_action(act, **kws)
```

Comment: It's returning the function object now. `<bound method Player.move_west of <player.Player object at 0xb718748c>>` but no change with the label.

Comment: to change text on button you will need reference to button but you don't save buttons references.

Comment: I'm just gonna try to rewrite it from scratch. This is first time I've tried making a GUI.